# PyMC for Model Averaging

Tags: pymc

I am interested in applying PyMC to model averaging. My goal is to estimate many linear models and average estimates across them, weighting by their posterior model probabilities. I am currently using the Bayesian Information Criterion (BIC) to approximate the likelihood of my data (therefore, my analysis is not fully Bayesian). I have successfully simulated a Markov Chain of models using one of my own scripts but I want to use PyMC because it seems like a great tool.

In my attempts thus far, I have not been forming the Markov Chain correctly. I am not visiting models with higher posterior weights more often than others. I will include the example code below. Please also see the IPython notebook [here](https://github.com/jtorcasso/pymc_example/blob/master/pymc_model_averaging.ipynb)! on github for the math markup and code together.

```
import numpy as np
from pymc import stochastic, DiscreteMetropolis, MCMC
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import random

def pack(alist, rank):

    binary = [str(1) if i in alist else str(0) for i in xrange(0,rank)]
    string = '0b1'+''.join(binary)
    return int(string, 2)

def unpack(integer):

    string = bin(integer)[3:]

    return [int(i) for i in xrange(len(string)) if string[i]=='1']


def make_bma():

    # Simulating Data
    size = 100
    rank = 20  

    X = 10*np.random.randn(size, rank)
    error = 30*np.random.randn(size,1)
    coefficients = np.array([10, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]).reshape((6,1))
    y = np.dot(sm.add_constant(X[:,:5], prepend=True), coefficients) + error

    # Number of allowable regressors    
    predictors = [3,4,5,6,7]

    @stochastic(dtype=int)
    def regression_model():

        def logp(value):

            columns = unpack(value)

            x = sm.add_constant(X[:,columns], prepend=True)

            corr = np.corrcoef(x[:,1:], rowvar=0)

            prior = np.linalg.det(corr)

            ols = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()

            posterior = np.exp(-0.5*ols.bic)*prior

            return np.log(posterior)

        def random():

            k = np.random.choice(predictors)

            columns = sorted(np.random.choice(xrange(0,rank), size=k, replace=False))

            return pack(columns, rank)

    class ModelMetropolis(DiscreteMetropolis):
        def __init__(self, stochastic):
            DiscreteMetropolis.__init__(self, stochastic)

        def propose(self):
            '''considers a neighborhood around the previous model, 
            defined as having one regressor removed or added, provided
            the total number of regressors coincides with predictors
            '''

            # Building set of neighboring models
            last = unpack(self.stochastic.value)
            last_indicator = np.zeros(rank)
            last_indicator[last] = 1
            last_indicator = last_indicator.reshape((-1,1))
            neighbors = abs(np.diag(np.ones(rank)) - last_indicator)
            neighbors = neighbors[:,np.any([neighbors.sum(axis=0) == i \
                                for i in predictors], axis=0)]
            neighbors = pd.DataFrame(neighbors)

            # Drawing one model at random from the neighborhood
            draw = random.choice(xrange(neighbors.shape[1]))

            self.stochastic.value = pack(list(neighbors[draw][neighbors[draw]==1].index), rank)

#        def step(self):
#            
#            logp_p = self.stochastic.logp
#            
#            self.propose()
#            
#            logp = self.stochastic.logp
#            
#            if np.log(random.random()) > logp_p - logp:
#                
#                self.reject()





    return locals()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    model = make_bma()
    M = MCMC(model)
    M.use_step_method(model['ModelMetropolis'], model['regression_model'])
    M.sample(iter=5000, burn=1000, thin=1)

    model_chain = M.trace("regression_model")[:]

    from collections import Counter

    counts = Counter(model_chain).items()
    counts.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x: x[1])

    for f in counts[:10]:
        columns = unpack(f[0])
        print('Visits:', f[1])
        print(np.array([1. if i in columns else 0 for i in range(0,M.rank)]))
        print(M.coefficients.flatten())
        X = sm.add_constant(M.X[:, columns], prepend=True)
        corr = np.corrcoef(X[:,1:], rowvar=0)
        prior = np.linalg.det(corr)
        fit = sm.OLS(model['y'],X).fit()
        posterior = np.exp(-0.5*fit.bic)*prior
        print(fit.params)
        print('R-squared:', fit.rsquared)
        print('BIC', fit.bic)
        print('Prior', prior)
        print('Posterior', posterior)
        print(" ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to do something akin to reversible jump MCMC, where you are sampling from the model space in addition to the parameter space(s). PyMC does not currently do rjMCMC, though it probably ought to. The trick is to account for the change in dimension when moving among models. If you do have a modest number of models, you can use an indicator function to select from the models, all of which are fit simultaneously.

Comment: I have accounted for the change in dimension, but decided to use my own code for MCMC sampling. Looking forward to rjMCMC in PYMC.